# LPU(H) generated by commutators?

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, lie-groups

I was told by my professor that the infinite dimensional projective unitary group $PU(\mathcal{H})$ for a separable Hilbert space $\mathcal{H}$ is generated by commutators, i.e. each element $u\in PU(\mathcal{H})$ can be written as a product of commutators $u = v_1w_1v_1^{-1}w_1^{-1} \cdot ... \cdot v_nw_nv_n^{-1}w_n^{-1}$ for $v_j, w_j \in PU(\mathcal{H})$. I have tried to find a source for this, but I was not successfull. The best I could find were vague hints that the Lie algebra of this space may be generated by commutators, at least for the finite case $PU(n)$, which might in the end lead to the desired result. Does anyone have any kind of material where I could look this up?

In the end, I'd like the loop group $LPU(\mathcal{H})$ to be generated by commutators. This would provide me with the desired result that there are no non-trivial continuous homomorphisms $\phi: LPU(\mathcal{H}) \rightarrow \mathbb{S}^1$, as $\mathbb{S}^1$ is abelian, which kills the commutators. Again, I can't seem to find anything related to this at all.

Any hints are very welcome! Thank you very much.